# React router v4 route onchange event

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

Is there any way to fire an event when route changes with react router v4. I need to fire a function on every route change. I use `BrowserRouter` and `Switch` from `react-router-dom` on client side in universal react-redux application.

Comment: The new V4 API no longer has an `onEnter` method, so that's not going to work here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resolved this by wrapping my application with an additional component. That component is used in a `Route` so it also has access to the `history` prop.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route component={App} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

The `App` component subscribes on history changes, so I can do something whenever the route changes:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    this.unsubscribeFromHistory = history.listen(this.handleLocationChange);
    this.handleLocationChange(history.location);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.unsubscribeFromHistory) this.unsubscribeFromHistory();
  }

  handleLocationChange = (location) => {
    // Do something with the location
  }

  render() {
    // Render the rest of the application with its routes
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do it in V4, but I didn't find any other extensibility points on the router itself, so this seems to work instead. Hope that helps.

Edit: Perhaps you could also achieve the same goal by wrapping `<Route />` in your own component and using something like `componentWillUpdate` to detect location changes.

Comment: Can I use history.createBrowserHistory method from history package when I need to change route on state change ?

Comment: @Dennis It's not what I expected but I'm satisfied, Thanks

Comment: There is a bug in `componentWillMount()`. It should be:
`const { history } = this.props.router;`

Answer (score 5):

**React: v15.x, React Router: v4.x**

*components/core/App.js:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class LocationListener extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleLocationChange(this.context.router.history.location);
    this.unlisten = 
this.context.router.history.listen(this.handleLocationChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();
  }

  handleLocationChange(location) {
    // your staff here
    console.log(`- - - location: '${location.pathname}'`);
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}    

export class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <LocationListener>
         ...
        </LocationListener>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

*index.js:*

```
import App from 'components/core/App';

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```